# Statistically comparing two surfaces (gams)

Tags: permutation, gam, mgcv, bam

I have been struggling with comparing two surfaces provided by a tensor product (by factor) from my gam model. To keep it simple, let's say the important part of the model looks like that:

y~te(a,b,by=factor)+covariate)

The model also includes random effects, let's say subject's ID.

The output is quite clear, the two groups differ their surfaces. What I would like to do is obtaining the spefic regions where they differ.

I have found functions in the "itsadug" package (plot_diff, plot_diff2) that provide some test on this regard, but from what I gathered, it seems the regions flagged as "significantly different" are based on uncorrected CIs. I have been thinking in using some sort of cluster-based permutation test, but it is not clear to me if this is the best approach, and how should I do it (still thinking).

If anyone has any idea, it would be great to discuss about it!

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Differences are found by computing simultaneous bayesian credible intervals! Hope it will be useful for someone else!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).